# Constructing a closed interval from open intervals of real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, interval-arithmetic

Is it possible to construct a closed interval, say [0,1] using only open intervals?

Ah, sorry. I should have said. Using the three set operations (union, intersection, complement) and open intervals of real numbers.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague; what operations do you allow in your construction? In some cases, the answer is trivial; in others, not.

Comment: Sorry, have edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tsemo Aristide's answer below shows how to answer the question assuming that you allow infinite intersections. However, even without this the answer is yes.

First, note that $[0, 1]=(-1, 2)\setminus ((-1, 0)\cup (1, 2))$ - here "$\setminus$" is set subtraction.

But $A\setminus B$ is just $A\cap B^c$ (here "$X^c$" denotes the complement of $X$).

Putting this together we can write $[0, 1]$ as the intersection of an open interval and the complement of the union of two open intervals.

Comment: Assuming $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, the complement of $((-1,0)\cup (1,2))$ is $\left(-\infty,-1\right]\cup\left[0,1\right]\cup\left[2,\infty\right)$. So when writing things out, $\left[0,1\right]$ is not constructed from open intervals, right?

Comment: @nluckn The OP is allowing complementation and intersection as well as union ("Using the three set operations (union, intersection, complement) and open intervals of real numbers."). $[0,1]$ is not a union of open intervals, but - as my answer says - it can be **constructed from** open intervals in the sense of the OP. Specifically, it's $$(-1,2)\cap(((-1,0)\cup(1,2))^c).$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $[0,1]=\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathopen]-1/n,1+1/n\mathclose[$.

Comment: If you want to use the “perverse notation” for intervals, do it right. `;-)`